# Partitioning a table on a column in another table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a fact table called `FactAccount` which has the following columns:

1. `AccountId` (identity)
2. `AccountMonthId` - FK referring to `DimMonth`
3. `AccountYear`

The DBA has done the partitioning on the `AccountYear` (2014, 2015, 2016...) column. But this table will be queried on the `AccountMonthId` column (with a join to `DimMonth`) where users will select the year and month from the `DimMonth` dimension table.

So in this case, I don't think the partitioning will make any difference as the `WHERE` clause doesn't filter by `AccountYear`.

The `DimMonth` dimension contains all combinations of year and month, i.e. 12 dimension members for each year and the `AccountMonthId` column is an identity column, not a natural key.

Is there a way to partition a table on a column in a table referenced by a foreign key? Or, to be very specific in my case, is it possible to partition the `FactAccount` table on `DimMonth.AccountMonthId`?

Comment: From what you are saying it sounds like your queries are pulling "All rows in February" regardless of year?  Most queries I've seen are going to need both Month and Year.

Comment: On @KennethFisher's note, does `DimMonth` contain one row per month (total of 12 rows) or one per (Year, Month)?

Comment: @DanielHutmacher - Yes, DimMonth has one row for each month and year combination. so for 2014, it has 12 rows, for 2015, it has 12 and so on.

Comment: @KennethFisher - I'll restrict based on DimMonth. Like Select * from FactAccount A inner join DimMonth m on a.AccountMonthId = m.MonthId where M.Month = 2 and m.Year = 2016

Comment: Is the `AccountMonthId` column an identity/sequence number, like 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, or is it a "natural key" that relates to the year and month value, like 201412, 201501, 201502, 201503, etc?

Comment: Its IdentityColumn for now. The only solution I could have though was change this to natural key based on Month and Year combination and then partition the FactTable based on this key in a range e.g. for 2014 it would be 201401 to 201412 and so on.? Do you also think thats the solution? and if thats the only solution?

Comment: The table is partitioned by year, but why can't an index on year key and month column be used to better satisfy queries inside a given partition?

Comment: @AronBertrand - There is no column for Month. The column Year was added just because DBA wanted to have this for partitioned. The column AccountMonth is a FK referring to DimMonth. And to your point to better satisfy the queries inside a given partition, is my whole point. per my understanding untill unless you specify the partition column in your where clause, the partition is not going to be effective. In this case all the where clause will be based on the DimMonth's year and Month and on the FactAccount.AccountYear.

Comment: So why doesn't your query look like this: Select * from FactAccount A inner join DimMonth m on a.AccountMonthId = m.MonthId where M.Month = 2 and m.Year = 2016 and a.AccountYearId = 2016. Also shouldn't there be a join between a & m on year?

Comment: Sounds to me like the table needs to be redesigned. I don't understand the need to partition by entire years instead of by months, or what value using a foreign key adds instead of just putting all of the date information into this table in the first place. I don't have a problem with joins to a dimension table to add other information, but if you're querying this table based on date range, you should be able to filter against JUST THIS TABLE rather than relying on join conditions to filter.

Comment: Are you open to a Partition Aligned Indexed View?  You will eat up more memory, more diskIO, but your reads will be very fast and with proper partition elimination, you'd theoretically use less memory.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **No**, you cannot partition by a column in another table, because that would cause problems whenever you change something in the "other" table - rows would magically have to move between partitions.

Summarizing some of the views in the comments from Aaron, Kenneth and me on your question:

- You could change `AccountMonthId` from a sequential number to a natural key, in this case an integer column from which you can compute the year and month. For example, the value 201503 could correspond to march 2015. This type of key is very common for date dimensions, because date dimensions don't change, so you can hard-code their keys.
- With a natural key for `AccountMonthId` you could partition on this column, `RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (201400, 201500, 201600)` or `RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (201499, 201599, 201699)`.
- Whether you have dates or just month values in your table, you could use a date column to store dates/months in your fact tables and in the month dimension. This would not only save storage space (three bytes, as opposed to four with int), it would also allow for your queries to use date functions among other gains. The same logic still applies with regards to partitioning.
- You can still achieve what's known as "partition elimination" (querying a single partition) in your current setup, as long as you include the partition column in your query. With your current setup, that could look something like `Select * from FactAccount A inner join DimMonth m on a.AccountMonthId = m.MonthId where M.Month = 2 and m.Year = 2016 and a.AccountYearId = 2016`
- You could partition on months instead of years. It'll take up the same disk space, although there are perhaps more partitions to manage, but this seems like a minor cost.
- Adding an extra column for the year and partitioning on that column seems a bit lazy, ignorant, or at least strange of your DBA.
- We have hardly touched on the subject of indexing - indexes, be they aligned or non-aligned, are often much more important than partitioning as performance goes.

Comment: I also don't quite understand the resistance to use an actual date there, e.g. `20150301` stored using a date data type instead of an integer. It actually takes less bytes (3), and adds all kinds of functionality (such as automatic constraint violation prevention and datepart magic that can eliminate a lot of dimension joins). Data warehousers have tried to convince me why such and such expert said that dimension keys always have to be integers but aside from name dropping their arguments aren't very convincing.

Comment: Agreed. Adding this to the answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: +100 for *why not an actual date* & *name dropping* :-)  I'm working on DWHs and never got that "store a date in an INT like 20150301*, invalid dates should be handled by the ETL process.

Comment: In all fairness, there are applications out there that use "special dates" (yuck!) for opening balances or year-end stuff. Those "dates" can look like 20151299, 20160000, etc, and for multiple reasons, they can't be mixed with regular dates. Breaks my heart every time, but at some point, I've just started accepting it as the norm. Slightly off-topic, though, because OP doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHutmacher. I would probably go with the Natural Key option.   And coming to the Actual date, we dont have the actual date in the data. Its just the Month and Year.

Comment: @Vikas That can still be made into a date.

Comment: Was *just* going to say that. :)

Comment: And as for the "special values" this is like storing 1900-01-01 to represent an unknown date, or -1 to represent no sales yet. These token values are problematic. Why does a "special date" need to exist in a fact table? That's rhetorical, this isn't the place for a full-blown discussion on this, but I bet I can come up with a better design that incorporates "special dates" without compromise.